# vim -- Ctrl + N -- disable recursive header search

Tags: vim

When working on C++ code, I often like to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to complete current word in edit mode.
However, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> starts searching recursively in header files. Our code-base is fairly huge, so such search takes several seconds to complete.

I'm used to different behavior, when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> completes using words in open tabs, and doesn't do extensive recursive search. How do I enable this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior depends on the value of `'complete'`. Read `:h 'complete'` for the full list of values. You probably want to remove `i` from the default value:

```
set complete-=i
```